# multi where / keys in update_batch

Tags: php, codeigniter

can someone help me, i want to update with this qty with `update_batch` with double keys (no_trans & stock_id)?

```
 $data = array(
       array(
          'no_trans' => '001' ,
          'stock_id' => 'aaa' ,
          'qty' => '100'
       ),
       array(
          'no_trans' => '001' ,
          'stock_id' => 'aab' ,
          'qty' => '200'
       ),
       array(
          'no_trans' => '002' ,
          'stock_id' => 'aaa' ,
          'qty' => '300'
       ),
       array(
          'no_trans' => '002' ,
          'stock_id' => 'aac' ,
          'qty' => '400'
       )
    );
```

i try with

```
$this->db->update_batch('table', $data, array('no_trans','stock_id'));
```

but is not work

Comment: Kindly post some of your code/ efforts.

Answer (score 1):

`update_batch` command **works with a single where clause**. (Just tested)

To archive your goal you have to use `foreach` with `update`/`replace` command

```
foreach ($data  as $key => $item) {
    $update = array(
        'qty' => $item['qty']
        );

    $this->db->where('no_trans', $item['no_trans']);
    $this->db->where('stock_id', $item['stock_id']);
    $this->db->update('table', $update);

    # or simple way /One Line

    $this->db->update('table', $update, array('no_trans' => $item['no_trans'], 'stock_id' => $item['stock_id'] ));
}
```